# count the number of groups of consecutive digits in a series of strings

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
p = (.35, .35, .1, .1, .1)
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['', 1] + list('abc'), (10, 20), p=p)).sum(1)

s

0    11111bbaacbbca1
1    1bab111aaaaca1a
2    11aaa1b11a11a11
3     1ca11bb1b1a1b1
4        bb1111b1111
5       b1111c1aa111
6     1b1a111b11b1ab
7        1bc111ab1ba
8      a11b1b1b11111
9        1cc1ab1acc1
dtype: object
```

---

I'm looking to count the number of groups of consecutive digits in each element of `s`.  Or, how many integers are in each string.

I'd expec the result to look like

```
0    2
1    3
2    5
3    6
4    2
5    3
6    5
7    3
8    4
9    4
dtype: int64
```

I'm looking for efficiency, though elegance is important too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** the idea is first to replace all consecutive groups of digist with single `1` and then delete everything which is not `1` and finally get the length of the changed string:

```
In [159]: s.replace(['\d+', '[^1]+'], ['1', ''], regex=True).str.len()
Out[159]:
0    2
1    3
2    5
3    6
4    2
5    3
6    5
7    3
8    4
9    4
dtype: int64
```

Timing against 100K Series:

```
In [160]: %timeit big.replace(['\d+', '[^1]+'], ['1', ''], regex=True).str.len()
1 loop, best of 3: 1 s per loop

In [161]: %timeit big.apply(lambda x: len(re.sub('\D+', ' ', x).strip().split()))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop

In [162]: %timeit big.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ').str.strip().str.split().str.len()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop

In [163]: big.shape
Out[163]: (100000,)
```

Timing against 1M Series:

```
In [164]: big = pd.concat([s] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [165]: %timeit big.replace(['\d+', '[^1]+'], ['1', ''], regex=True).str.len()
1 loop, best of 3: 9.98 s per loop

In [166]: %timeit big.apply(lambda x: len(re.sub('\D+', ' ', x).strip().split()))
1 loop, best of 3: 11.7 s per loop

In [167]: %timeit big.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ').str.strip().str.split().str.len()
1 loop, best of 3: 12.6 s per loop

In [168]: big.shape
Out[168]: (1000000,)
```

Explanation:

```
In [169]: s.replace(['\d+', '[^1]+'], ['1', ''], regex=True)
Out[169]:
0        11
1       111
2     11111
3    111111
4        11
5       111
6     11111
7       111
8      1111
9      1111
dtype: object
```

**OLD (slow) answer:**

What about using [.str.extractall()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) in conjunction with [.groupby(level=0)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html)?

```
In [130]: s.str.extractall('(\d+)').groupby(level=0).count()
Out[130]:
   0
0  2
1  3
2  5
3  6
4  2
5  3
6  5
7  3
8  4
9  4
```

Explanation:

```
In [131]: s.str.extractall('(\d+)')
Out[131]:
             0
  match
0 0      11111
  1          1
1 0          1
  1        111
  2          1
2 0         11
  1          1
  2         11
  3         11
  4         11
3 0          1
  1         11
  2          1
  3          1
  4          1
  5          1
4 0       1111
  1       1111
5 0       1111
  1          1
  2        111
6 0          1
  1          1
  2        111
  3         11
  4          1
7 0          1
  1        111
  2          1
8 0         11
  1          1
  2          1
  3      11111
9 0          1
  1          1
  2          1
  3          1
```

Answer (score 4):

PiRSquared and MaxU solutions are great.

However, I noticed `apply` is usually a bit faster than using multiple string methods.

```
In [142]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: len(re.sub('\D+', ' ', x).strip().split()))
1 loop, best of 3: 367 ms per loop

In [143]: %timeit s.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ').str.strip().str.split().str.len()
1 loop, best of 3: 403 ms per loop

In [145]: s.shape
Out[145]: (100000L,)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution

```
s.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ').str.strip().str.split().str.len()
```

***100,000 rows***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
p = (.35, .35, .1, .1, .1)
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['', 1] + list('abc'), (100000, 20), p=p)).sum(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one! It would be interesting to compare timings on bigger series...

Comment: @MaxU added timing

Comment: You may want to benchmark `s.apply(lambda x: len(re.sub('\D+', ' ', x).strip().split()))` as well. With couple of str methods over there, apply is 10% faster.

Comment: @piRSquared, it's not fair! Why did you accept my answer which is two times slower???

Comment: @piRSquared, BTW, inspired by your solution i'm trying to get rid of empty elements when using: `s.str.split('\D+')`

Comment: @MaxU What isn't fair is to ask a question with a pre-made answer.  I wanted to solicit other's thoughts.  Your answer was most useful in that it gave me an idea I didn't already have ;-)

Comment: @JohnGalt indeed... I added timing, you should post an answer